# jQuery IE 9 Datepicker error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.18.  I have a page that works just fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE 9.
I get the following error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'inline': object is null or undefined 
jquery-ui.min.js, line 12 character 29775
```

The code it references is the datepicker code, so here's how I add datepicker to two different elements (note this is inside `$(document).ready(function(){`):

```
$('#revisedShipDate').datepicker({
    onSelect: revisedShipDate,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});

$('#nextCallDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

Has anyone seen this before and know what I can do to resolve it?

Comment: Is the code inside DOM Ready handler

Comment: Yes it is.  Updated the question for clarification.

Comment: I've tested this code in IE9 (http://jsfiddle.net/9jEna/) and I'm not getting that error. Could you provide the HTML or maybe some more context?

Comment: Had to strip out a lot of stuff for security reasons, but here's what I can give you: http://pastebin.com/4HGCCju5

Comment: Are you getting that error when trying to pull the calendar in this page? http://jsfiddle.net/UuqPF/1/show/

Comment: No.  I don't get the error on there.  That mean it has to be something with the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running into similar problems with a datepicker and customers to our site that use IE9

What I've found:

IF the OS is 64-bit AND IE9 being run is the 32-bit version (id by looking for WOW64 in the browser id strings (navigator.appVersion), then the datepicker fails to fire.

See: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-don-t-work-in-ie-9

And see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx  (about half way down the page under "Feature Tokens") for the WOW64 reference

So far, choices for solution seem to be limited to work-arounds:

1. force the browser version back to 7 or 8 using a metatag
2. ask one's customers to run in compatibility mode
3. ask customers to ensure they're running the 64-bit version of IE9
   when running from a 64-bit OS.